# How do you get Pikachu as a starting Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I heard it is possible to get Pikachu as a starting pokemon in Pokemon Go. How do you do this?

Comment: How has the "Possible duplicate:" comment got 10 upvotes, while the actual close vote is only at 3? *Have we all spent our votes closing Pokemon Go questions, today?*

Comment: @Timelord64 I can't close questions so upvoting is the next best thing

Comment: @Timelord64 I'm glad you mentioned this. For some reason (it seems silly to me now), I thought that upvoting the comment generated by a close vote would have the same effect as submitting the close flag myself. TIL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to get Pikachu as a starter Pokemon. It's actually considered an easter egg in the game.

You can get it by walking away from the starter Pokemon several times when they appear. The 4th time they will reappear with a [Pikachu](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Pikachu) next to them.